# RecyclerVIew item width doesn't fill screen width

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view

I'm filling a `RecyclerView` with custom view as a list item, `ListItem`, creating it from the `onCreateViewHolder` function.

The problem is, the list item view's width isn't filling the recyclerview (the parent) width, but in reality it wraps the width of the content (it's set to match_parent not wrap_content).

I'm guessing that since I'm creating the view programmatically, it has no knowledge of it's parent.

Here's where I create the `ListItem` in the adapter:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public ListItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ListItemHolder(new ListItem(parent.getContext()));
}
```

And the code for `ListItem`

```
public class ListItem extends LinearLayout {

    private ListItemBinding binding;
    private final Context mContext;

    public ListItem(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        setUp();
    }

    public ListItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        setUp();

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ListItem, 0, 0);
        setBigText(a.getString(R.styleable.ListItem_bigText));
        setSmallText(a.getString(R.styleable.ListItem_smallText));
        setImageDrawable(a.getDrawable(R.styleable.ListItem_src));
        setHeaderText(a.getString(R.styleable.ListItem_header));
        showHeader(binding.listItemHeaderText.getText() != null);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public void setUp() {
        binding = ListItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(mContext), this, true);
        setClickable(true);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void setBigText(@Nullable String text) {
        binding.listItemBigText.setText(text == null ? "" : text);
    }

    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I tried passing the parent as a parameter to the `ListItem` constructor and inflating with that but it raised an error relating to the context.

How can I inflate the `ListItem` while keeping it as a seperate class and making it fill it's parent width?

I could create a layout of the list item and inflate from a layout in `onCreateViewHolder` instead of inflating from a custom view class but I want to
have it separated and reusable.

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to @Zain, hes solution was just to set the width to MATCH_PARENT through the view class,
apparently it ignores the xml.

The change I did:

```
public class ListItem extends LinearLayout {
    .
    .
    .

    public void setUp() {
        binding = ListItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(mContext), this, true);
        setClickable(true);
        setFocusable(true);
        *setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));*
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set it while instantiating it in `onCreateViewHolder()`:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public ListItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    ListItem listItem = new ListItem(parent.getContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                                     MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
    listItem.setLayoutParams(params);
    return new ListItemHolder(listItem);
    
}
```

Comment: Oh wow that actually worked lol, because I set the width to match_parent in the xml so I wouldn't expect it to change mid run