# Fill width Imageview in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview and it shows a list of images. My need is to fit its width according to the width of parent i tried many codes but i am unable to do it .

Also tried scaletype = " centrecrop"

recycler view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    >
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/adsRV_AD"
                    android:overScrollMode="never"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    />
    
</layout>
```

My item layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_img"
        android:outlineProvider="background"
        android:src="@drawable/booknow"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        />
</layout>
```

Result :
[image]
My references :
[How to scale an Image in ImageView to keep the aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio)

[ImageView doesn't fill entire width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780538/imageview-doesnt-fill-entire-width)

[Why image don't fill width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236642/why-image-dont-fill-width)

[Scale Image to fill ImageView width and keep aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077325/scale-image-to-fill-imageview-width-and-keep-aspect-ratio)

[Resizing ImageView to fit to aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400113/resizing-imageview-to-fit-to-aspect-ratio)

[Scale ImageView to fit screen width/height while maintaining aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209873/scale-imageview-to-fit-screen-width-height-while-maintaining-aspect-ratio)

[RecyclerVIew item width doesn't fill screen width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630808/recyclerview-item-width-doesnt-fill-screen-width)

Comment: Can you please share the XML that contains your recycler view? Also, do you want the image to fill the width of the screen and take up the white space (to the right in your screenshot)?

Comment: done please check

Comment: Can you share the entire XML layout that contains the recycler view? What you have shared doesn't give me much info unfortunately.

Comment: yes added full xml code

Comment: I think you are specifying custom width in @drawable/bg_rounded_img

Answer (score 1):

The problem might not be in the item layout but in the RecyclerView layout.

Try to be sure that the item usese the full width in the RecyclerView.

Comment: <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/adsRV_AD"
                    android:overScrollMode="never"

                    android:clipToPadding="false"

                    />

Comment: please check , post edited